# Spring code returning 'view' works differently when using Ajax call from JS and when sending POST with form in JSP

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, request-mapping

I am using JavaScript Ajax calls to a specific requestMapping for returning a corresponding 'view'. In the console I can see that the dispatcherServlet completed with response 200 OK. But it does not propagate from there; it doesn't show the view it is supposed to show.

However, when sent from JSP POST using form, it enters the same requestMapping and returns the correct JSP view I want.

I have inspected the POST package I'm sending, and figured out that when I was using JSP POST, the contentType was explicitly set as 'application/x-www-urlencoded', hence I applied the same thing for Ajax with ajaxSetup. But it still didn't work.

Ajax Call

```
$.ajaxSetup({contentType: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"});
$.ajax({
type:'post',
url: getContext() + '/auth',
processData:true,
data:{
      status: "authenticated"
}
```

})

main_menu.jsp

```
<script>
var user_name = "${username}"
</script>
- This JSP contains other JS codes in <script/> to follow
```

RequestMapping code in @Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleAuth(
        @RequestParam("status") String status) {
    if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("authenticated"))
        return "main_menu";
    return "";
}
```

Result when "main_menu" was returned from requestMapping '/auth' using POST from JavaScript Ajax call

```
20:24:56.389 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG 
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView - View name 
'main_menu', model {}
20:24:56.396 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG 
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to [/WEB- 
INF/views/main_menu.jsp]
20:24:56.492 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 200 OK
```

Result when "main_menu" was returned from other requestMapping, '/login'
You can see that other JS files were called with GET method from the DispatcherServlet. The model field is filled this time. When I filled the model field when using '/auth' with the exact same thing, it didn't work.

```
20:52:11.154 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView - View name 'main_menu', model {username=admin, org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.username=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors, password=1111, org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.password=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors}
20:52:11.154 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView - Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/views/main_menu.jsp]
20:52:11.156 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 200 OK
20:52:11.173 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/infosender/js/popup.js", parameters={}
20:52:11.174 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/infosender/js/main_initialization.js", parameters={}
20:52:11.174 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/infosender/js/folderadd.js", parameters={}
20:52:11.174 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["/js/"]
20:52:11.174 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - GET "/infosender/js/keywordset_init.js", parameters={}
hello world!
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem coming from not understanding the difference between form request and ajax call.

Simply put, 
* form request : when view (jsp or other html templates) is changing
* ajax call : when only data is being transmitted (view does not change)

I hope nobody gets confused with this matter like I did.